# If destination and source are the same, what does memmove do?

Tags: c, realloc, memmove

If destination and source are the same, does `memmove` still "move" the data (or does it return directly)? What about `realloc`; what if the new size is the same as the old size?

Comment: And what if a tree falls in the forest but no one is around to hear it? Ah, the great mysteries of life!

Comment: You can check glibc source code at http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git

Comment: On a related note, I don't care what it "does", I just want to know if it is well-defined. This, from the man page, seems quite clear that it is OK to have destination equal to the source: *"copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest, and the bytes are then copied from the temporary array to dest."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's really going to be implementation-specific.  It would be good practice to do so, sure, but it really depends *which* implementation you mean.

It's going to work either way, but presumably a suitably clever implementation would check for overlapping segments (and particularly for the case where `source == dest`) and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: Actually, I disagree that it would be good practice. Suppose you are moving tiny blocks of memory, a test and a potential branch misprediction could be a very costly price for the assumption that the programmer doesn't know what he is doing. That said, if the arguments can be determined at compile-time to be equal then yes, it would be good to do it (e.g: using gcc's `__builtin_constant_p`)

Comment: @ninjalj, good point.  The real point I was making was that there is no guarantee of such behaviour, and an implementation is essentially to do anything it wants (within reason...)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know no standard gives any promises about returning immediately in such case, so you should not expect this behavior.

Better do not pass invalid pointers in hope it's not going to access the data ;-)

Comment: "invalid pointers". There is nothing incorrect about having an identical source and destination. Assuming, of course, that valid data can be read there. I guess your point is that we shouldn't expect `memmove(NULL,NULL,1)` to work?

Comment: More or less. What I mean is yes, we shouldn't be passing invalid pointers (NULL or other inaccessible or readonly memory area) in hope that memmove will do nothing since it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

At least for `realloc`, it is implicitly assumed that a "no move necessary" condition exists and is valid, since moving is noted as a special case:

> The realloc() function shall change the size of the memory object pointed to by ptr to the size specified by size. The contents of the object shall remain unchanged up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. **If** the new size of the memory object **would require movement** of the object, the space for the previous instantiation of the object is freed.

The wording "if... would" suggests that this is not necessarily always so. Of course there is **no requirement** at all for an implementation to omit a copy that is not necessary.

The only requirement for `memmove` is that the final effect is the same as if the data was copied to a temporary buffer first and then copied to the final destination. This "as if" constraint allows the copying of overlapping regions without corrupting data (no implementation that I know *really* copies to a temporary buffer first).

So, in one word: unspecified.

Comment: Is that wording from the Standard? I didn't expect to see a grammar error in there. :D

Comment: That is copied verbatim from IEEE Std 1003.1/2004 (though emphasis is mine), which claims to be "aligned with the ISO C standard".

Comment: @PaulManta: what grammar error? You know, some of us are not native English speakers.

Comment: @ninjalj Neither am I. It's the "if ... would" part. The correct way to say it is "if the new size of the memory object requires ...". http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/difficulties/ifiwouldhave.html

Comment: @PaulManta: I think in this case that use is right. It's a real conditional, not a _that didn't happen in the past_ case. Anyway, this is OT, so I'll shut up.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the spec doesn't require a shortcut, and it's not clear when adding the extra branch actually improves performance.

But that doesn't answer the question of what is actually happening when you call `memmove`. I dug through the glibc source code and found many assembly implementations for various architectures along with a portable C implementation.

The TL;DR is that the pure C version does not shortcut, but the x86_64 assembly version does (I think).

The pure C version is a fairly standard memmove loop. The one trick is that if you are moving 16 KiB or more, it will manipulate virtual memory instead of copying bytes. The function is defined in [string/memmove.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=string/memmove.c;hb=HEAD), and the meat of the implementation is the `BYTE_COPY_FWD` macro from [sysdeps/generic/memcopy.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=sysdeps/generic/memcopy.h;hb=HEAD).

For x86_64 assembly, there are several versions depending on available instructions (e.g. AVX, SSE, etc). Those are in [sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch;hb=HEAD).

Here is one implementation from [memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S;hb=HEAD) that uses Enhanced REP MOVSB (ERMS):

```
ENTRY (__memmove_erms)
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        /* Skip zero length.  */
        test    %RDX_LP, %RDX_LP
        jz      2f
L(start_movsb):
        mov     %RDX_LP, %RCX_LP
        cmp     %RSI_LP, %RDI_LP
        jb      1f
        /* Source == destination is less common.  */
        je      2f
        lea     (%rsi,%rcx), %RDX_LP
        cmp     %RDX_LP, %RDI_LP
        jb      L(movsb_backward)
1:
        rep movsb
2:
        ret
L(movsb_backward):
        leaq    -1(%rdi,%rcx), %rdi
        leaq    -1(%rsi,%rcx), %rsi
        std
        rep movsb
        cld
        ret
END (__memmove_erms)
```

My ability to read assembly isn't great, but from what I can tell, this implementation does shortcut the case where source and destination are the same.

If I read this correctly, it starts by comparing the pointers. If the destination comes before the source, it jumps to label 1 (`jb 1f`) which calls `rep movsb`. As I understand it, this is basically an instruction for `memcpy`. If the pointers are equal, it jumps to label 2 (`je 2f`) which returns immediately. Otherwise it arranges for a `rep movsb` to run backwards over the data.

I also took a look at the SSSE3 implementation in [sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S;hb=HEAD). That version also appears to implement the shortcut.

Obviously, all of this only applies to glibc. I haven't checked llvm-libc.